# How do I create an ArrayList of Y-axis values for a LineGraph in Kotlin using MPChartsLirary?

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am trying to add values to a dataset  in the Y-Axis but I don't seem to understand how to do that.
I want to add two values, a float and an integer.
Below is my code, it works when it was in Java but when I translated to Kotlin, it stopped to work. I am new to Kotlin and doing my first app using MPAndroidCharts.

```
    //Create an array list of Y-Axis values
    private fun setYAxisValues():ArrayList<Entry> {
        val yVals = ArrayList<Entry>()
        yVals.add(Entry(60, 0))
        yVals.add(Entry(48, 1))
        yVals.add(Entry(70.5f, 2))
        yVals.add(Entry(100, 3))
        yVals.add(Entry(180.9f, 4))
        return yVals
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. Just add an `f` to every float value: `60f` or `60.toFloat()`

Comment: Is there an alternative way to do this ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. If `Entry` class requires `Float` you must provide `Float`.